# Excel lookup function

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have the following table:

```
            Col A   B     C    D
Row 1      Rating   2     3    5
Row 2         3     0   0.89  0.96
```

I am currently doing a lookup function (=lookup(0.874,B2:D2,B1:D1)) but it's looking at the next smallest number closest to 0.874 in Row 2 (0) and returning a 2.  I want it to actually look at which number it's closest to in Row 2, 0 or 0.89 (0.874 is closest to 0.89) and pick 3 from Row 1.  How do I go about changing my function so I can get this to work?

If my lookup value was 0.95, the return number would be 5, and so on.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this formula

`=INDEX(B1:D1,MATCH(MIN(ABS(B2:D2-F1)),ABS(B2:D2-F1),0))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

where F1 contains your lookup value

`ABS(B2:D2-F1)` finds the absolute differences of `B2:D2` from your lookup value, so if you `MATCH` the minimum of those against the list of those you get the position of the closest value to F1....and `INDEX` returns the corresponding value from `B1:D1`